# PHP Parse Question

Tags: php

I am trying to edit a link image.

http://site.com/image.jpg

I would like it to be http://site.com/tn-image.jpg

I want to add the tn- with php. How can I accomplish this? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [dirname](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) in conjunction with [basename](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) to alter a path.

```
<?php
$path = "http://site.com/image.jpg";
echo dirname($path).'/tn-'.basename($path);
```

[Test it.](http://codepad.org/GKDZWE0e)